# Excel: How to average all numbers in column B that have the same number in Column A?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, datatables, average

How can I calculate the average of all numbers in column H that have the same number in column C.

For example how can I output the average of all H values that have a C value of 2?

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: AVERAGEIF formula.

Comment: Hi thanks you are absolutely right. Do you want to post to get the points?  =AVERAGEIF(A1:A10,2,B1:B10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AVERAGEIF, e.g.

```
=AVERAGEIF(C:C,2,H:H)
```